# How can i adjust the img height in one column to the height of the height in another column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

In a 2 flex bootstrap columns, I would like to adjust the height of the image on the right column to the height of the text in the left columns. How could I achieve this ?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: img { height: 100% }

Comment: img { height: 100% } does'nt work

Comment: Are you sure ？I edited your code. The image is as tall as the text

Comment: Actually it doesn't work if the image is taller

Comment: Ok, I understand your question. Because the questions are marked as repetitions, I cannot answer them below. You can use an empty tag, Add the image as a background.
Set `.bgimg {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`